# What SQL query should I perform to get the result set expected?

Tags: sql, mysql, recursion

What SQL query should I perform to get the result set expected, giving the first element of the chain (2) as input data, or any of them ?

```
table name: changes
+----+---------------+---------------+
| id | new_record_id | old_record_id |
+----+---------------+---------------+
|   1|              4|              2|
|      -- non relevant data --       |
|   6|              7|              4|
|      -- non relevant data --       |
|  11|             13|              7|
|  12|             14|             13|
|      -- non relevant data --       |
|  31|             20|             14|
+----+---------------+---------------+


Result set expected:

+--+
| 2|
| 4|
| 7|
|13|
|14|
|20|
+--+
```

I know I should consider change my data model, but: What if I couldn't?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm going on the assumption there aren't a fixed number of records that could be returned, so a list of joins is out of the question (to traverse the tree). However, what signals the end of the list? (is it when the `new_record_id` doesn't have a mating `old_record_id`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should work to get your result

```
CREATE TABLE #return(val int)
DECLARE @VAL int
SET @VAL = 2

WHILE (SELECT count(*) FROM [changes]
WHERE old_record_id = @VAL) > 0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #return values(@VAL)

SELECT @VAL = new_record_id FROM [changes]
WHERE old_record_id = @VAL
END
INSERT INTO #return values(@VAL)
SELECT * FROM #return
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're vague on the database, here is some good literature:

**MySQL**

Look around section 7, this goes in to hierarchy and recursive functions
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html

**MSSQL**

Good article on the same thing (you're going to find functions the common place, though MSSQL can use WITH).
http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/06/simple-family-tree-query-using.html

**PostgreSQL**

Same type of article. All these have the same premise, working your way up a database tree from child to parent.
http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=24

Answer (score -1):

if you have data in the middle that you do not want to update then the only solution would be

```
update table set id=2 where id=4;
update table set id=4 where id=7;
update table set id=7 where id=13;
update table set id=13 where id=14;
update table set id=14 where id=20;
```

But this update might work if it does the updates in the order they appear which will generally happens if you have the pk of the table set to id.

```
update table set id=(select min(id) from table b where b.id>table.id)
```

You can also force this by adding an `order by i`d at the end, and let you see if it allows that.